# blazor service with async dictionary?

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, blazor, blazor-webassembly

i wanted to Build in blazor something like dictionary service
so i have

in startup    `builder.Services.AddScoped<DictService>();`

Dict service is like:

```cs
public class DictService
{
    private readonly IHttpService _ihttp;

    public DictService(IHttpService ihttp, ILogger<DictService> logger) =>
        _ihttp = ihttp;

    static Dictionary<string,List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>> IntStrDictLocalCache
        = new();

    public async ValueTask<List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>> GetAllIntStrDict(
        string DictName)
    {
        if (!IntStrDictLocalCache.ContainsKey(DictName))
            await FillIntStrDict(DictName);
        return IntStrDictLocalCache[DictName];
     }

    public async ValueTask<string> GetIntStrDictVal(int? Key , string DictName)
    {     
        if (Key == null) return string.Empty;
        if (!IntStrDictLocalCache.ContainsKey(DictName))
            await FillIntStrDict(DictName);
        return IntStrDictLocalCache[DictName].Where(x=>x.Key== Key).Single().Value;
    }

    private async Task FillIntStrDict(string DictName)
    {
        IntStrDictLocalCache[DictName] = await _ihttp
         .Get<List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>>("api/Dicts/IntStr/all/" + DictName);
    }
}
```

and now i have table like

```xml
@inject DictService _ds;
<MudTable Items="@List1">
<HeaderContent>
    <MudTh>Dict1Col1</MudTh>
    <MudTh>Dict2Col1</MudTh>
    <MudTh>Dict2Col2</MudTh>
</HeaderContent>
<RowTemplate>
    <MudTd DataLabel="Dict1Col1">
        @_ds.GetIntStrDictVal(@context.Dict1Col1,"Dict1")</MudTd>
    <MudTd DataLabel="Dict2Col1">
        @_ds.GetIntStrDictVal(@context.Dict2Col1,"Dict2")</MudTd> 
    <MudTd DataLabel="Dict2Col2">
        @_ds.GetIntStrDictVal(@context.Dict2Col2,"Dict2")</MudTd>        
</RowTemplate>
</MudTable>
```

and when i initially go to the page with table
i see blanks values (not even ints that should be translated)
if i change something that will call statehaschanged then i see correct translated values (or when it is not first time for dict - it is already in this `cache` then it is also fine from beginning)
where should i add this statehaschanged for this to work? i believe it should be in this service but this is impossible?
and also
WHY i see that `FillIntStrDict` is loaded not only once but multiple times
looks like that `GetIntStrDictVal` is called like  `n` times all at once that's why for each call `if (!IntStrDictLocalCache.ContainsKey(DictName))` is false and it loads same Dictionary multiple times ?

what can i do to fix this?

-----------edit
so @lsit 1 is ant list of class
lets say that gender is INT

```
 @list1 = new List<User>() = new() {new user(){id=1;name = a; gender=x} }
```

so for this exapmle it would be

```
   <MudTd DataLabel="Gender">
    @_ds.GetIntStrDictVal(@context.gender,"GenderDict")</MudTd>
```

Comment: What is `@List1` in MudTable? `@context.Dict1Col1` doesn't make a lot of sense without it.

Comment: i adited / added explenation ;)

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't use await in the razor component, you'll need to read the values from your dictionary service e.g. inside OnInitializedAsync() like so

```
    List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> Dict1Col1 { get; set; }
    List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> Dict1Col2 { get; set; }
       
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
         Dict1Col1 = await _ds.GetIntStrDictVal(context.Dict1Col1, "Dict1");
         Dict1Col2 = await _ds.GetIntStrDictVal(context.Dict1Col2, "Dict1");
         await base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }
```

Then you can bind your razor to the Dict1Col1 member variable.

To avoid that your dictionary will be loaded multiple times, you can wrap that initialization inside some sort of locking mechanism. A SemephoreSlim would be good solution: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim?view=net-6.0

Your service loading could look something like this:

```
private static SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);

private async Task FillIntStrDict(string DictName)
{
    try
    {
        await semaphore.WaitAsync();

        IntStrDictLocalCache[DictName] = await _ihttp.Get<List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>>("api/Dicts/IntStr/all/" + DictName);
    }
    finally
    {
        semaphore.Release();
    }            
}
```

Comment: It's far better to use a ConcurrentDictionary instead of a Semaphore. Besides, SPAs are single threaded due to browser restrictions. Blazor 7 adds multithreading through workers as an experimental feature

Comment: thanks thats what i thought but i did not wanted to have to override this  protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync() in every place where i need dicts - it will be in hunderets of components with time... . is there any other way ? or maybe better way to handle this kind of need ?
ps. thanks for semaphore also
if i do this in FillIntStrDict it does not change anything - it stoll load multiple times but like with siungle thread ;P i would need to use this semaphore in GetIntStrDictVal. not shure if it is best way but will work :)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Can You please show how to fix this multiple loads using ConcurrentDictionary  ?

Comment: Maybe it's better if you create a base class for your components where all required dictionaries will be loaded in the OnInitializedAsync(). The derived component classes can then be configured with a list of dictionary names that should be loaded.